# App Icon in "All Apps" blurred

Tags: windows-runtime, icons, scale, windows-10, uwp

I am developing an universal Windows 10 App. My problem: In the list "All Apps" on Windows 10 Desktop (Build 10586) is the app icon verry blurry. Also there is a border in the system color around it. I provided for the Square44x44.png the scales 100, 125, 150, 200, 400 and the targetsizes 24, 32, 40 and 48 (all unplated). The Icon in the app list has the dimensions 32x32 so I thought, windows uses the targetsize-32 icon. But it looks like a bigger resolution is downsampled with a very bad algorithm. The Icon in the Taskbar shows sharp and without any border.

[image: The displayed icon in the app list]

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use a high resolution, square image as base image for generating icons and splashes to get better result. I use [UWP Tile Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09611e90-f3e8-44b7-9c83-18dba8275bb2) extension myself. Also there is [UWP Visual Assets Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3c94468-96bc-4860-8860-4458ab3bc467) extension that I did not check yet. Also try to design your icon with suitable thickness, it help to have less blurry effect in sizing.

To get an icon with no border set a background color suitable for your app in Package.appxmanifest, it's transparent by default.

If you did not yet, take a look at [Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets).